# How do I get rid of the padding in p element

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of the white bottom padding in the P element that I have labelled the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgJct.png) with in this [code pen](http://codepen.io/Rob100/pen/grzPAd) with?

I have tried making the padding 0 in it and everything round it but that hasn't worked

Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
  font-size: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-family: lobster, Monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  /* 80px/16=5em */
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-style: ;
}
blockquote {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Puritan', cursive;
  color: black;
}
.img-r {
  /* other definitions */
  width: 100%;
}
.padding {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
li {
  font-family: Monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  /* 80px/16=5em */
  text-decoration: ;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-style: ;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .jumbotron p {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
.pad {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<h1> 
        Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley
        </h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6">
            <h2 style="color: #645340; text-decoration: underline;" class="text-
            center">AboutDame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley </h2>
            <ul class="text-center pad">

              <li class="text-center"><em>Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley 
    was born as Vera Buchthal to a Jewish father, a judge in Dortmund who lost his post to the Nazi regime, and a non-Jewish Viennese mother.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>In July 1939, at the age of five, Shirley arrived, together with her nine-year-old sister Renate, to Britain as a Kindertransport child refugee.She was placed in the care of foster parents living in the Midlands town of Sutton Coldfield.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>After leaving school Vera decided not to go to university (botany was the "only science then available to my gender") but sought employment in a mathematics/technical environment. At the age of 18, she became a British citizen and changed her name to Stephanie Brook.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>After leaving school Vera decided not to go to university (botany was the "only science then available to my gender") but sought employment in a mathematics/technical environment. At the age of 18, she became a British citizen and changed her name to Stephanie Brook.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>In the 1950s, Stephanie worked at the Post Office Research Station at Dollis Hill, building computers from scratch and writing code in machine language. She took evening classes for six years to obtain an honours degree in mathematics. In 1959, she moved to CDL Ltd, designers of the ICT 1301 computer.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>After marriage to a physicist, Derek Shirley, in 1962, Shirley founded, with a capital of £6, the software company Freelance Programmers</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em> She wanted to create job opportunities for women with dependents, and predominantly employed women, with only 3 male programmers in the first 300 staff,[8] until the Sex Discrimination Act 1975 made that practice illegal.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>She adopted the name, Steve, to help her in the male-dominated business world.[9] Her team's projects included programming Concorde's black box flight recorder.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>Shirley retired in 1993 at the age of 60 and has since focused on her philanthropy.</em>
              </li>
              <li class="text-center"><em>Shirley was appointed Officer of the Order of the British Empire (OBE) in the 1980 Queen's Birthday Honours, for services to industry and promoted Dame Commander (DBE) in the New Year Honours, 2000 for services to Information Technology.</em>
              </li>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail padding">
              <img class="img-responsive img-r center-block padding" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/480xn/p014nf75.jpg">
              <div>
                <p class="text-center">
                  Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a browser specific rule. Not sure about others, but to get rid of it in Chrome, use:

```
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
```

I'm assuming the rest follow the same vendor prefix pattern, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I added this to my css

.margin-after {
  webkit-margin-after: 0px;
}

and this to the p tag in question 

<p class="text-center margin-after"> 
   Dame Stephanie "Steve" Shirley 
   </p> 
Was that what I was meant to do because there was no change?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @rdm100 What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tested it on Firefox and Chrome, there was no change in either.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my css and applied the class to the p element.

It gets rid if the spacing below the p element. But the p element displays bunched up when the window is made smaller, which it didn't do before.

How do I fix that?

```
.margin {
padding-top: 18px;
line-height: 0; 
}
```

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reputation to comment..
If your intent is just to have the text centered in the `p`, all these hacky rules aren't needed..Just set a proper line-height and pad however you want;

```
.jumbotron p {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 0px; /* adjust freely */
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

You could just go with only line-height as well, it will stay vertically centered..

Comment: Hi, thanks ffor your reply. Your way works to take the padding out but when I resize the window making it smaller, the p text overflows the thumbnail area. Do you know how to stop that? 
Using my margin class works to take the padding out too but messes the text up in a different way, which I describe above. The p element only displays correctly within the thumbnail box when I don't take the bottom padding out so far.
Any ideas?